# openshift/node docker container fails with HOST_ETC: unbound variable

Tags: openshift-origin

After downloading openshift/node Docker container the container fails to run:

```
$ docker logs 64e3eeb60cbc
/usr/local/bin/origin-node-run.sh: line 15: HOST_ETC: unbound variable
```

This is on Windows 7 with Docker Quickstart Terminal.  I ran it with

```
docker run -d openshift/node
```

Probably I need to set HOST_ETC in the command line or elsewhere, but I can find no documentation on using this Docker image, so would like some guidance on what to fix here, and any other additional settings that might be required but undocumented.

Thanks for any expert advice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The official documentation](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html#running-in-a-docker-container) is telling to start the container this way:

```
$ sudo docker run -d --name "origin" \
        --privileged --pid=host --net=host \
        -v /:/rootfs:ro -v /var/run:/var/run:rw -v /sys:/sys -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:rw \
        -v /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes:/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes \
        openshift/origin start
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's for Origin itself including the master and nodes both, right?  Is it any different if I am using openshift/node, to just be running a node?

Comment: The openshift/origin image is for one container which is master and node. I don't use the node image. This is the place where it's going wrong for you: https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/images/node/scripts/origin-node-run.sh

Comment: With the code tip, I could deduce that the command needed at least one modification:  `docker run -d -e HOST_ETC="C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc" openshift/node` to run correctly.  The container now at least stays running, so might be more to configure yet but it is much closer now.  Thanks!